# How much storage does this Swift struct actually use?

Tags: xcode, swift, pointers, memory

Suppose I have the following struct –

```
struct MyStruct {
    var value1: UInt16
    var value2: UInt16
}
```

And I use this struct somewhere in my code like so -

```
var s = MyStruct(value1: UInt16(0), value2: UInt16(0))
```

I know that the struct will require 32-bits of storage  for the two 16-bit integers –

What I am not certain about is whether swift is allocating two additional 64-bit pointers for each value in addition to one 64-bit pointer for the variable `s`.

Does this mean total storage requirement for the above code would result in the following?

```
MyStruct.value1     - 16-bits
MyStruct.value1 ptr - 64-bits
MyStruct.value2     - 16-bits
MyStruct.value2 ptr - 64-bits
s ptr               - 64-bits
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Total               - 224-bits
```

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: My program has very strict memory requirements and I need to optimize storage as much as possible. Pointer storage is a known killer for eating memory unnecessarily and I am trying to understand how to best optimize my code.

Comment: Very true but I'm really only dealing with primitives such as in my example above. Aside from the auto-growth behavior behind Array and Dictionary, is there any other type of additional memory overhead introduced by Swift that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyStruct is 4 bytes because `sizeof(UInt16)` is 2 bytes. To test this for any given type, use `sizeof`. `sizeof` return the memory in bytes.

```
let size = sizeof(MyStruct) //4
```

If you want to get the size of a given instance you can use `sizeOfValue`.

```
var s = MyStruct(value1: UInt16(0), value2: UInt16(0))
let sSize = sizeofValue(s) //4
```

I believe the size of the pointer will depend on the architecture/compiler which is 64-bits on most computers and many newer phones but older ones might be 32 bit.

I don't think there is a way to actually get a pointer to `MyStruct.value1`, correct me if i'm wrong (i'm trying `&s.value1`.

### Pointers

Structs in Swift are created and passed around on the stack, that's why they have value semantics instead of reference semantics.

When a struct is created in a function, it is stored on the stack so it's memory is freed up at the end of the function. It's reference is just an offset from the Stack Pointer or Frame Pointer.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you are correct regarding the architecture. What I am trying to understand is when Swift will internally create a pointer and when it will not.

Comment: Oh I see what you're thinking. Structs are allocated on the stack while classes are allocated on the heap. You (mostly) use pointers to give an address into the heap. Structs on the stack (usually) don't need to be passed around by reference/with a pointer. When they are passed into functions their values are copied. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. Yes, I am aware of the stack / heap semantics. I'm relatively certain that Swift needs to retain a pointer to s so it can be recalled from memory at some point later down the line, even though the value is stored on the stack.

Comment: At the end of a function, the stack frame where structs are stored is gone. All of that memory doesn't need to be kept around

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It'll be four bytes on the stack.

Comment: Hi Atamiri, can you please elaborate? Does the variable 's' require any pointer storage?

Answer (score 1):

Just try it in a XCode Playground:

[image: Sizeof MyStruct]

The answer is 4 bytes.

Comment: There are no pointers. UInts are structs themselves. So, they don't use references (unlike class-based objects). So that total space used for any variable of type `MyStruct` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here but how would the value be recalled from memory when it needs to be passed to a function? Is the address stored temporarily in a register?

Comment: I'd have to know more about the compiler to be sure, but if it's anything like most C/C++ compilers, it would compute the offset of the object from some base. If your variable is declared within a function, the base would be the start address of the runtime stack frame. At runtime the offset would be added to the stack frame start address (from a register) to obtain the start address of the object.

Comment: Thank you again, LIProf. That really helps clarify things for me.